# What is SELinux's regex type?

Tags: find, regular-expression, selinux

I'm trying to locate all files on my system matching an SELinux file context (fcontext).
These contexts are specified using some regex, and I'd like to use `find -regex ...` to the same effect.
However, `find` has several types of regex:

- emacs (default)
- posix-awk
- posix-basic
- posix-egrep
- posix-extended

I tried looking at the source of policycoreutils (`apt-get source policycoreutils`) but didn't see which regex is being used.
I guess "The differences are minute and nothing to obsess about" is also an answer.

Comment: Are you asking what regex SELinux uses or how to translate a specific regex to make it work with `find`?

Comment: What regex SELinux uses. I hope I won't have to translate anything

Comment: OK, I'm just trying to understand how `find` comes into it. The most widespread regex flavor is the BRE (posix-basic for find) so that's your best bet.

Comment: Going by examples, they're ERE or close enough, so `posix-egrep` or `posix-extended` (between which the differences are minute).